# Shifting slots in a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, analytics, data-analysis, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with four columns like below and for every customer, I have 12 rows with below details as shown in the sample

```
Cust_id|slot|trigger_id|coup_type
1|       1| 2101| null
1|       2| 2102| null
1|       3| 2103| null
1|       4| 2104| null
1|       5| 2105| product
1|       6| 2106| null
1|       7| 2107| null
1|       8| 2108| product
1|       9| 2109| null
1|       10| 21010| null
1|       11| 21011| product
1|       12| 21012| product
```

Now I need to perform slot shifting based on coup_type such that all product coup should be present in slot7-10 and allocation should always start from slot7. after shifting slot should be rearranged like below:-

```
Cust_id|slot|trigger_id|coup_type
1|       1| 2101| null
1|       2| 2102| null
1|       3| 2103| null
1|       4| 2104| null
1|       5| 2105| null
1|       6| 2106| null
1|       7| 2105| product
1|       8| 2108| product
1|       9| 21011| product
1|       10| 21012| product
1|       11| 21009| null
1|       12| 21010| null
```

I need to perform this operation in pyspark.

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `row_number` by ordering the column `coup_type` and make it the row number as the join key with the `slot` column. If the column is not continuous, then you may need another column for the ordering row number of the `slot` column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Cust_id').orderBy(desc('coup_type'))

df2 = df.withColumn('slot', row_number().over(w) + 7 - 1).drop('trigger_id')
df2.show(12, False)

+-------+----+---------+
|Cust_id|slot|coup_type|
+-------+----+---------+
|1      |7   |product  |
|1      |8   |product  |
|1      |9   |product  |
|1      |10  |product  |
|1      |11  |null     |
|1      |12  |null     |
|1      |13  |null     |
|1      |14  |null     |
|1      |15  |null     |
|1      |16  |null     |
|1      |17  |null     |
|1      |18  |null     |
+-------+----+---------+

df.drop('coup_type').join(df2, ['Cust_id', 'slot'], 'left').show(12, False)

+-------+----+----------+---------+
|Cust_id|slot|trigger_id|coup_type|
+-------+----+----------+---------+
|1      |1   |2101      |null     |
|1      |2   |2102      |null     |
|1      |3   |2103      |null     |
|1      |4   |2104      |null     |
|1      |5   |2105      |null     |
|1      |6   |2106      |null     |
|1      |7   |2107      |product  |
|1      |8   |2108      |product  |
|1      |9   |2109      |product  |
|1      |10  |21010     |product  |
|1      |11  |21011     |null     |
|1      |12  |21012     |null     |
+-------+----+----------+---------+
```